24.10 lost HDMI Sound (after logout)
After reboot boot, the sound is ok and I see in settings the HDMI output. Firefox with youtube is ok.
I am not sure to 100%, I think after "logout" (auto logout) then I lost the HDMI sound. I see this in settings has no more HDMI output.
I must reboot the system, then I have back the sound.
I only had this problem with 24.10, I had no problem before (24.04).
Update: I have a workaround
systemctl --user restart pipewire

According to my observation of the problem, this occurs after a certain period of time when the computer is idle.
Guido
